# Firefox: Black background behind icons on windows firefox web extension

Tags: css, windows, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

On Firefox on windows, we are getting the black background behind icons (a span with the image set as background).
The content of `popup.html`:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Project Name| Samlple</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="accounts" class="thumbnails">
    <li class="created_from_template autofill">
      <a>
        <span alt="15Five" data-powertiptarget="js-toolTipBody-538" class="app-icon js-toolTip" style="background-image: url(&quot;http://localhost:3000/uploads/service/logo/1/15five.png&quot;);"></span> 
        <span class="notice-icon"></span>
      </a>
      <span id="js-toolTipBody-538" class="js-toolTipBody toolTipBody">
          15Five
      </span>
      <span class="serviceName">15Five</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

And CSS:

```
.thumbnails > li > a > .app-icon {
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.thumbnails > li > a > span {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 12px;
  max-width: 80px;
}

.thumbnails > li > a:hover > span {
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  transform: scale(1.05);
}
```

Issue:

[image: Icon-with-black-behind]

Tried using transitions but that not preferred as that is moving elements. Also, the issue seems only limited to Windows OS, on Linux it seems to be working fine on firefox. So, suspecting some graphics support issue.

How can I get rid of this black background issue? Really appreciate the help.

PS: Not setting the background to black anywhere.

Comment: Try by adding the  "background-color: transparent!Important" for that icon

Comment: @Govind Thanks! even with `background-color:  transparent !important;` issue persist.

Comment: Oh Bad. @Kamesh Can you share the code in fiddle

Comment: That's for firefox web extension. I'm afraid, won't be able to set up Firefox web extension environment on fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well resolving this was a bit tricky as it was platform specific rendering issue.

So to resolve it, made changes in layout.

```
.thumbnails {
  height: 395px; /* 520px (popup height) - 50px (header) - 55px (search bar) - 20px (Footer) */
  padding: 32px 20px 8px 30px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
  background: #fff;
}
.thumbnails > li {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 101px;
  min-height: 146px;
  display: block;
  /* please be careful with changing margins and paddings - Firefox on Windows has some rendering issues */
  margin: 0 0 0 -1px;
  padding: 8px 10px 8px 11px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn .5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) both;
  animation: fadeIn .5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) both;
  animation: fadeIn .18s linear both;
  background: #fff;
}
```